# How to make Powershell break when one of the commands returns 1

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that is used in one of the jobs of a GitLab CI (previously the code was placed directly in the yml file, but now it has grown in size). The script mainly consists of calls to the [dotnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) command. I've noticed that all error outputs are now suppressed and the script does not break when one of the commands returns 1. Same thing happens when the script is run by the runner and when I call the script from PowerShell (so the core of the problem is unrelated to GitLab CI). When I call the dotnet commands directly in Powershell error output is not suppressed.

Can I make the script break on first returned 1 while keeping the error output?

I know that I can check `$LASTEXITCODE` after every command and add `2>&1` at the end of every command, but is there a better way?

I tried setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and wrapping command calls try catching, but it doesn't appear to do anything against commands that are external applications.

---

Example script:

```
Write-Host "Restore nuget packages" -ForegroundColor Blue
dotnet restore

Write-Host "Build solution" -ForegroundColor Blue
dotnet build

Write-Host "Run tests" -ForegroundColor Blue
dotnet test

# "dotnet test" returns an error and writes what went wrong to error output.
# The script should stop here without suppressing the error output.
# This should be the default behavior for all commnds calls within this script.

Write-Host "Upload report" -ForegroundColor Blue
ReportUploader report.xml
```

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop` should be enough

Comment: Put everything in a [Try/Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally), it should stop at the first command that encounters an error.

Comment: [Changes to preference variable only take effect in scripts and functions if those scripts or functions are *defined in the same scope* as the scope in which preference was used. For more information, see about_Scopes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables)

Comment: I'm not sure why error output was suppressed, as with further tests I they started showing up. Unfortunately `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` doesn't appear to affect commands returning 1. This works `if($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) { exit 1 }`, but adding it to every command seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: Did you set `$ErrorActionPreference` at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2):

> This works `if($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0) { exit 1 }`, but adding it to every command seems to be a bad idea.

One approach to deal with this is to wrap your commands in scriptblock literals (`{...}`) so you can execute them *later* - then you can just repeat the same invocation and error checking routine for them all:

```
$tasks = @(
  @{ Command = { dotnet restore };            Label = "Restore nuget packages" }
  @{ Command = { dotnet build };              Label = "Build solution" }
  @{ Command = { dotnet test };               Label = "Run tests" }
  @{ Command = { ReportUploader report.xml }; Label = "Upload Report" }
)

# now we can repeat the same routine for each task
foreach($task in $tasks){
  # Write status message
  Write-Host $task['Label'] -ForegroundColor Blue

  # Invoke command
  & $task['Command']

  # Test exit code
  if($LASTEXITCODE -gt 0){
    Write-Host "Task '$($task['Label'])' failed with exit code ${LASTEXITCODE}"
    exit 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer by Mathias, I came up with this solution:

```
Function RunCommand {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  Param (
    $Command
  )
  Process {
    echo $Command
    & $Command
    $ExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
    if ($ExitCode -gt 0){
      throw "Command '$Command' exited with code $ExitCode"
    }
  }
}
```

I can now use this function in my CI script or any other script. I've added the `echo` because GitLab logs the output and it might be helpful to know what command was called when things went wrong. I've replaced exit with an exception so I can handle it PowerShell way if I need to. With this function applied, my CI script would look something like this:

```
. .\RunCommand.ps1
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Write-Host "Restore nuget packages" -ForegroundColor Blue
RunCommand { dotnet restore }

Write-Host "Build solution" -ForegroundColor Blue
RunCommand { dotnet build }

Write-Host "Run tests" -ForegroundColor Blue
RunCommand { dotnet test }

Write-Host "Upload report" -ForegroundColor Blue
RunCommand { ReportUploader report.xml }
```

Note: My function is saved in the same directory as the script in a file named **RunCommand.ps1**.